# How we show that the cohomology rings of product of 2-sphere and connect sum of projective plane are isomorphic?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

How we show that the following ring isomorphism
$$H^{*}(S^{2}\times S^{2};\mathbb{Q})\cong H^{*}(\mathbb{C}P^{2}\sharp \mathbb{C}P^{2};\mathbb{Q}).$$

Comment: They are not isomorphic.  Count the number of things in $H^2$ which square to $0$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: For any $\Bbb F$ they are not isomorphic?

Comment: @Kevin.S:  You have to be careful with what you mean by "generators".  The point is that an isomorphism need not map one set of preferred generators to another set of preferred generators.  In particular, if you change $\mathbb{C}P^@\sharp \mathbb{C}P^2$ to $\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp - \mathbb{C}P^2$, then the rational cohomology rings are isomorphic, and yet your generator comment applies to this situation as well.

Comment: @C.F.G:  Actually, they are isomorphic for the field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}[i]$.  If $a,b\in H^2(S^2\times S^2;\mathbb{Q}[i])$ are the "usual" generators, (so $a^2 = b^2 = 0$ while $ab$ generates $H^4$), and if $x,y\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp \mathbb{C}P^2; \mathbb{Q}[i])$ are the "usual" generators (so $x^2 = y^2$ generates $H^4$ and $xy = 0$), then an isomorphism is given by $a\mapsto x+iy $ and $b\mapsto x-iy$.